# Removing duplicate using sql

Tags: sql, select, duplicates

I have asked this question before but not able to get the link.

The question is:

I have flight table containing following values:

```
From_City To_City Fare
 A         B      50000
 B         A      50000
 A         C      60000
```

How to remove either A to B or B to A since it conveys the same meaning.

The Final output should be:

```
  From_City To_City Fare
 A         B      50000
 A         C      60000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `exists` operator. Since you only want to remove one row of a pair of duplicates, you need to make an arbitrary decision which one to keep and which one to eliminate. In the following query I decided to keep the one with the lower `from_city`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   flights a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   flights b
                   WHERE  a.from_city = b.to_city AND
                          a.to_city = b.from_city AND
                          a.fare = b.fare AND
                          b.from_city > b.to_city)
```

Comment: @DreamerP yes. Strings in SQL have total order.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
select f.*
from flights f
where f.from_city < f.to_city
union all
select f.*
from flights 
where f2.from_city > f.to_city and
      not exists (select 1
                  from flights f2
                  where f2.from_city = f.to_city and
                        f2.to_city = f.from_city and
                        f2.fare = f.fare
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fares are always the same between any two cities no matter the direction, you could group by the "sorted" pair and get the maximum (or minimum, they are the same per assumption) fare.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN from_city > to_city,
           THEN to_city
         ELSE from_city
       END from_city,
       CASE
         WHEN from_city > to_city,
           THEN from_city
         ELSE to_city
       END from_city,
       max(fare) fare
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY CASE
                  WHEN from_city > to_city,
                    THEN to_city
                  ELSE from_city
                END,
                CASE
                  WHEN from_city > to_city,
                    THEN from_city
                  ELSE to_city
                END;
```